# Safari extension running injected javascript multiple times

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I have copied the code from the following example on the Apple Developer site.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW1

When I run the extension, it runs normally except the injected script is run 3 times causing the output to be written to console.log 3 times. I also put a alert in the doBigCalc function and it opened 3 alerts.

Why is this happening/is it supposed to happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't speak to your implementation, but it could be that your code isn't the problem. The key is understanding that an injected script is loaded .... From the [injected script documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH6-SW1):

> Scripts are injected into the top-level page and any children with HTML sources, such as iframes. Do not assume that there is only one instance of your script per browser tab.

Comment: I just read that. I just added if (window.top === window) and it fixed it.

Comment: Thanks @RobWilkerson.  I've been tearing my hair out for an hour.  This solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation mentions that you can dispatch messages using event handlers on three different levels:

```
safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.addEventListener("message", waitForMessage, false);

safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.addEventListener("message", waitForMessage, false);

safari.application.addEventListener("message", waitForMessage, false);
```

But you should choose one of the the three. You aren't attaching event listeners to all three are you? If you are, you'll get it run three times for sure.